# Testing nested resource controllers with Rspec and Factory girl in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have a nested resource specialty under user.

My **routes.rb** looks like

```
  resources :users do
     resources :specialties do
     end
  end
```

My **factories.rb** looks like

```
Factory.define :user do |f|
  f.description { Populator.sentences(1..3) }
  f.experience { Populator.sentences(1..5) }
  f.tag_list { create_tags }
end

Factory.define :specialty do |f|
  f.association :user
  specialties = CategoryType.valuesForTest
  f.sequence(:category) { |i| specialties[i%specialties.length] }
  f.description { Populator.sentences(1..5) }
  f.rate 150.0
  f.position { Populator.sentences(1) }
  f.company { Populator.sentences(1) }
  f.tag_list { create_tags }
end
```

My **Specialties_controller.rb** looks like

```
class SpecialtiesController < ApplicationController

def index
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @specialties = @user.specialties
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @specialties }
    end
  end
```

My **specialties_controller_spec.rb** looks like

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe SpecialtiesController do
  render_views

  describe "GET 'index'" do
    before do
      @user = Factory.create(:user)
      @specialty = Factory.create(:specialty, :user => @user)
      @user.stub!(:specialty).and_return(@specialty)
      User.stub!(:find).and_return(@user)
    end

    def do_get
      get :index, :user_id => @user.id
    end

    it "should render index template" do
      do_get
      response.should render_template('index')
    end

    it "should find user with params[:user_id]" do
      User.should_receive(:find).with(@user.id.to_s).and_return(@user)
      do_get
    end

    it "should get user's specialties" do
       @user.should_receive(:specialty).and_return(@specialty)
       do_get
    end
   end
 end
```

The first two tests pass, but the last test fails with the error message

```
Failure/Error: @user.should_receive(:specialty).and_return(@specialty)
       (#<User:0x007fe4913296a0>).specialty(any args)
           expected: 1 time
           received: 0 times
```

Does anybody have an idea what this error means and how to fix it? I've looked at similar posts and can't find an error in my code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
@user.should_receive(:specialty).and_return(@specialty)
```

`specialty`is a one-to-many relation and should be plural: `specialties`. And indeed you have in your controller:

```
@specialties = @user.specialties
```